# How to set cron job but only using ftp details i dont have cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, cron

I am developing application in codeigniter ,i want to run my controller method every mid night where i am updating status of some table field according to date wise.

I know it can be done using cron job with cPanel ,but client does not have cpanel ,he has only ftp details,so any one has idea how i can set cron job using ftp ? any script which run automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to set cron job URL in server. URL can run by server on particular time you set in server. - Thanks!

Comment: I dont have access of cpanel or site server,i have only ftp details.he has given me phpadmin server details and ftp details for site,so i i have uploaded site code using ftp details and uploaded database on database server,so now problem is client saying i dont have cpanel details something where i can set cron tab? if any body has idea how to write shell script something?

Answer (score 1):

Normally CLI from Codeigniter require access to SSH terminal to add a cron job via `crontab -e` or if you have cpanel via cronjobs panel.

The solution can be if you can call the address via `GET` so in this case you can add a cron job in another server and call that address with `GET`.

Add cron via SSH on shell:

Login to SSH shell via Putty on Windows, Terminal on Mac and Terminal on Linux:

Type: `crontab -e`

(If you don't have an editor pre-selected it will ask you to choice one, i recommend "nano")

Add a new line:

```
59 23 * * * /path/to/codeigniter/index.php controller Method
```

and it will call every day at 23:59 the Controller "controller" and Method 'Method"

Cheers

Comment: I think setting cron in another server it is not right solution but how i can call  "CLI from Codeigniter require access to SSH terminal to add a cron job via crontab -e" any example ,It will be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to set up a cron job on your server using ftp. What you could do is put all the script you want to run in a single page and use a service like www.pingdom.com to visit that page every midnight.

Dan